# "Limit on" or "Limit to"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in meaning between "limit to" and "limit on".

A report of some sentences that I found on Google book follows:

**Limit to**

> - It may be noted that the annual **limit to** the eye lens (150 mSv) is related directly to the threshold dose for cataracts (approximately
>     5Sv)
> - Hence, the static method represents the lower **limit to** the true ultimate load and has a maximum factor of safety
> - These reductions were attributed to an intervention in the normal course of events which was identified as the reduction of the speed
>     **limit to** 55 mph

**Limit on**

> - (B) Replacing the plan's previous annual **limit on** mental health benefits with a $500,000 annual **limit on** all benefits (including
>     medical/surgical and mental health benefits);
> - The **limit on** bank guarantees was removed and fully delegated to commercial banks

Comment: This Google Ngram chart might be interesting: http://goo.gl/jHQMj8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between the actual limit, and what is limited:

*The limit on loans was changed to 5,000* - you have a limit on loans, and the limit changed to 5,000...
Likewise there is a limit on speed, it's limited to 55mph...

Sometimes, like the first example, it's less obvious, & I suspect you just have know how it's working in the sentence - the limit is on the radiation exposure permitted, & it's limited to 150mSv.